# How to sort a string alphabetically in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to reorder the string "hearty" to be in alphabetical order: "aehrty"

I've tried:

```
val str = "hearty"
val arr = str.toCharArray()
println(arr.sort())
```

This throws an error. I've also tried the `.split("")` method with the `.sort()`. That also throws an error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use `sorted()` and after that `joinToString`, to turn the array back into a String:

```
val str = "hearty"
val arr = str.toCharArray()
println(arr.sorted().joinToString("")) // aehrty
```

**Note:** `sort()` will mutate the array it is invoked on, `sorted()` will return a new sorted array leaving the original untouched.

Answer (score 8):

So your issue is that `CharArray.sort()` returns `Unit` (as it does an in-place sort of the array). Instead, you can use `sorted()` which returns a `List<Char>`, or you could do something like:

```
str.toCharArray().apply { sort() }
```

Or if you just want the string back:

```
fun String.alphabetized() = String(toCharArray().apply { sort() })
```

Then you can do:

```
println("hearty".alphabetized())
```